# What is the intuition of the outer product of two states?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere, state-space-geometry

If it is possible give me an intuition both with vectors on the plane and on the Bloch-Sphere.

Comment: Hi Jimarious :). I guess the question, as it is described now, is not connected with the tags: `physical-realization` and `physical-qubit`. Is there any connection that I don't see?

Comment: No, there is no underlying connection, I just cannot create tags, but was forced to add five tags so I could post this question. You can edit this if you want.

Comment: Ok :). how I remember one can use less than 5 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer product of two states is a matrix. Here are some often used outer products:

\begin{equation}
|0\rangle \langle 0 | =
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
|0\rangle \langle 1 | =
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}
\\
|1\rangle \langle 0 | =
\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
|1\rangle \langle 1 | =
\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

For any $2$ by $2$ matrix we can write:

\begin{equation}
M = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} = 
a|0\rangle \langle 0 | + b|0\rangle \langle 1 | +c |1\rangle \langle 0 | +d|1\rangle \langle 1 |
\end{equation}

How to calculate the outer product of two vectors:

\begin{equation}
|v\rangle \langle w | =
\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} w_1^{\dagger}&w_2^{\dagger}\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} v_1 w_1^{\dagger} & v_1 w_2^{\dagger} \\
v_2 w_1^{\dagger} & v_2 w_2^{\dagger}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The outer product of a state from the Bloch sphere $|\psi\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ with itself:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle \langle \psi | = 
\begin{pmatrix} |\alpha|^2 & \alpha \beta^{\dagger} \\
\beta \alpha^{\dagger} & |\beta|^2 \end{pmatrix} = \rho
\end{equation}

It is equal to the density matrix $\rho$ that also describes the state of the system like the wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$ and has correspondence with the same point on the Bloch sphere as the $|\psi\rangle$ state.

Another useful thing to know about the outer products of two states. Assume we have orthonormal eigenbasis $|v_s \rangle$ and we have this matrix $| w \rangle \langle v_1 |$ (that is not a unitary matrix and $|w\rangle$ is some normalized state). What will be after the multiplication of this matrix with a geneal $|\psi \rangle = \sum_s \alpha_s |v_s\rangle$ state vector:

$$| w \rangle \langle v_1 | \sum_s \alpha_s |v_s\rangle = \alpha_1 | w \rangle$$

This kind of outer products are often used in QC. For example, for $X$ operator we can write:

$$
X = | 0\rangle \langle 1| + | 1\rangle \langle 0|
$$